# JSF 2 + Spring Security 3.1.x @Secured AccessDeniedException handling

Tags: jsf, spring-security

I'd like to ask how can I handle (e.g. catch, log and redirect flow ) AccessDeniedException that comes from 'security annotation' (@PreAuthorize, @Secured, etc...)?

I tried setting my own AccessDeniedHandler:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

but it seems, that it intercepts only exceptions that are raised when I try to get to unauthorized resource.

But exception that comes from

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public void myMethod(){
    System.out.println("Secret Method");
}
```

is not handled that way.

Comment: Are you sure you properly configured you method protection? I mean `<global-method-security pre-post-annotation-handling="enabled"/>`? Are you sure AccessDeniedException is thrown?

Comment: yes, I configured it <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
  jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/> and yes, "AccessDeniedException: Access is denied"  is thrown

Comment: Show your whole spring security configuration

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, so i guess you don't need an answer anymore. Still answering this for other people:

First: You are right: `<access-denied-handler ref="myAccessDeniedHandler" />` only handles requests for resources, so you need something different for handling AccessDeniedExceptions thrown by your own code or by Spring-Security because of `@PreAuthorize`.

What you can do is using Spring-AOP/AspectJ to write an around-aspect with a pointcut referencing all methods that are annotated with a specific annotation (in your case @PreAuthorize)

see [JSF2 with SpringSecurity: handle AccessDeniedException of @Secured-Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536188/jsf2-with-springsecurity-handle-accessdeniedexception-of-secured-annotation) for an example of handling `@Secured`-annotations